# Problem with local progress bar code while it works properly on CodePen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a Progress Bar Liquid Bubble CodePen which works fine.
You can change `val` variable and it creates a progress animation from 0 to `val` value.

Here is the CodePen in action:

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/yrvRKZ?editors=0110

Now the problem is **I'm losing that animation** (The liquid movement from 0 to `val` value) when I create my HTML, JS and CSS file locally on my laptop and copy-paste the exact code from codepen!!!

Note:  I've added sources for JS and CSS and Jquery to my HTML file too...

Here is the local code which is not working properly as I said:

```js
 var colorInc = 100 / 3;
            $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
    
    var val = 80;
    
     setTimeout(function(){
      
             if (val < 50) {
            $(".progress").parent().addClass("red");  
    } else if (50 <= val && val <= 80 ) {
            $(".progress").parent().addClass("orange");
    } else {
            $(".progress").parent().addClass("green");
    }
    
    }, 2000)     
    
          
    
    
        
    // Set the initial percent
    $(".progress .percent").text(0 + "%");
    
    // Set animation start
    $(".progress .water").css("top", 100 + "%");
    
    // Trigger animation in 2000ms (2 seconds)
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".progress .percent").text(val + "%");
    
    $(".progress .water").css("top", 100 - val + "%");  
    }, 2000)
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #1a1a1a;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #ccc;
    }
    input[type="text"] {
      background-color: transparent;
      margin-top: 30px;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #8080ff;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #518bf0;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px #518bf0;
      width: 45px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-bottom: dashed 1px #ff8080;
    }
    input::-moz-selection {
      color: #1a1a1a;
      background-color: #c6e4ee;
    }
    input::selection {
      color: #1a1a1a;
      background-color: #c6e4ee;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #7aa6f3;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
      color: #7aa6f3;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #7aa6f3;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #7aa6f3;
      text-shadow: 0 0 3px #7aa6f3;
    }
    .wrapper {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: box;
      display: flex;
      -o-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -o-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -o-box-orient: vertical;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .green {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .green .progress,
    .red .progress,
    .orange .progress {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .green .progress,
    .red .progress,
    .orange .progress {
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    .green .progress {
      border: 5px solid #53fc53;
    }
    .green .progress {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #029502;
    }
    .green .progress,
    .red .progress,
    .orange .progress {
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .green .progress .inner,
    .red .progress .inner,
    .orange .progress .inner {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 2;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .green .progress .inner,
    .red .progress .inner,
    .orange .progress .inner {
      width: 240px;
      height: 240px;
    }
    .green .progress .inner,
    .red .progress .inner,
    .orange .progress .inner {
      border: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
    }
    .green .progress .inner,
    .red .progress .inner,
    .orange .progress .inner {
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water,
    .red .progress .inner .water,
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
      left: -50%;
      border-radius: 40%;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      -webkit-animation-name: spin;
      animation-name: spin;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water {
      top: 25%;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water {
      background: rgba(83,252,83,0.5);
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water,
    .red .progress .inner .water,
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water,
    .red .progress .inner .water,
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-duration: 10s;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .water {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #03bc03;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .glare,
    .red .progress .inner .glare,
    .orange .progress .inner .glare {
      position: absolute;
      top: -120%;
      left: -120%;
      z-index: 5;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .glare,
    .red .progress .inner .glare,
    .orange .progress .inner .glare {
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    }
    .green .progress .inner .glare,
    .red .progress .inner .glare,
    .orange .progress .inner .glare {
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .percent,
    .red .progress .inner .percent,
    .orange .progress .inner .percent {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .percent,
    .red .progress .inner .percent,
    .orange .progress .inner .percent {
      line-height: 240px;
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .percent {
      color: #03c603;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .percent {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px #029502;
    }
    .green .progress .inner .percent,
    .red .progress .inner .percent,
    .orange .progress .inner .percent {
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    .red {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .red .progress {
      border: 5px solid #ed3b3b;
    }
    .red .progress {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #7a0b0b;
    }
    .red .progress .inner .water {
      top: 75%;
    }
    .red .progress .inner .water {
      background: rgba(237,59,59,0.5);
    }
    .red .progress .inner .water {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9b0e0e;
    }
    .red .progress .inner .percent {
      color: #a30f0f;
    }
    .red .progress .inner .percent {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px #7a0b0b;
    }
    .orange {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .orange .progress {
      border: 5px solid #f07c3e;
    }
    .orange .progress {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #7e320a;
    }
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      top: 50%;
    }
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      background: rgba(240,124,62,0.5);
    }
    .orange .progress .inner .water {
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #a0400c;
    }
    .orange .progress .inner .percent {
      color: #a8430d;
    }
    .orange .progress .inner .percent {
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px #7e320a;
    }
    #copyright {
      margin-top: 25px;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #b3b3b3;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #copyright div {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #copyright a,
    #copyright a:link {
      color: #808080;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
    #copyright a:active {
      color: #b3b3b3;
    }
    #copyright a:hover {
      color: #b3b3b3;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
    .instructions {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    
    
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      
     
      
      <div class="green">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="percent"><span>0</span>%</div>
            <div class="water"></div>
            <div class="glare"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Wrap your jQuery in a document.ready() handler or move it to the end of the page

Comment: Can you please create an answer.... Moving what? Moving this line    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
  to the end of the page crashed the whole code...:(

Comment: No, move *your* script. `<script src="Script.js"></script>`

Comment: What !!! it worked...

Comment: Thanks for the comment... If you create an answer I'll choose it as the correct one...

Comment: No need. I closed your question as a duplicate of another one with the same problem and answer.